# RedHat Virtualization Manager | Spice access from different subnets

Tags: virtualization, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have the following I think unusual setup:

[image: Diagram]

1. The RedHat Virtualization manager and host are hosted on the same hardware, and are using on hardware. The Manager is dualhomed: one virtual nic for the internal network (between the host and the manager) and one nic for the connectivity to the outside world.
2. The client is supposed to connect to their dedicated virtual desktop through a simple VPN
3. Since the choice goes to  spice instead of RDP or VNC, the incoming connection request from the end user is targeting the Host (RHEL virtualization Host) on  specific ports.
4. The connection requests from the end user go through the manager (RHEL virtualization manager) first then lands on the host, but is never successful.
5. Routing /packet forwards is enabled on both servers.

So I came up with the following findings:

1. A simple ping from connected end user to the host is not successful: the packet "ICMP echo request" lands correctly on the host, and the corresponding "ICMP echo reply" is there, but
2. the "ICMP echo reply" is not seen even in the manager, it is like is it is lost somewhere/ I checked the ovirtmgmt interface configuration but nothing could point me to even a hint.
3. Checked the iptables rules on both the manager and the host ... but no results.
4. Both ping from host to manager and manager to host are successful, so the communication between the two are fine. The Spice VMs are even accessible when inside the Local area network.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hint on how to address this issue. Thank you. Be safe everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone come accross the same issue. By design the manager / engine doesn't allow an incoming connection from an outside network (meaning: outside their own subnets) to go through. In order to fix this a spice proxy is required. Thus, after implemented the proxy (which in this case has to have 2 NICs - outside and inside networks) and let the engine know the existence of such proxy, the issue is fixed.